# How can I use one storyboard for multiple objects in Silverlight?

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, storyboard

I'm using one animation for three different images. How would I target all three with the same `Storyboard` ? Thanks....

C#

```
public TheGame()
{
     InitializeComponent();
     CompositionTarget.Rendering += new EventHandler(CompositionTarget_Rendering);
     FadeImageStoryboard.Begin();
}
```

XAML;

```
<UserControl 
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"


xmlns:sdk="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/sdk" x:Class="Capitals.TheGame"

mc:Ignorable="d"
d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="400" Height="480" Width="640" KeyDown="UserControl_KeyDown" >

<Canvas x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="#FF6AC3FF" >

    <Grid x:Name="MyGrid" Height="235" Canvas.Left="10" Canvas.Top="85" Width="620" >
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Grid.Resources>
            <Storyboard x:Name="FadeImageStoryboard">
                <DoubleAnimation From="1.0" 
                             To="0.3" 
                             Duration="0:0:2"
                             RepeatBehavior="Forever"
                             AutoReverse="True" 
                             Storyboard.TargetName="cloud1"
                             Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" />
            </Storyboard>
        </Grid.Resources>


        <StackPanel Grid.RowSpan="2">

            <Image x:Name="cloud1" Source="Cloud.png" Height="115" Width="184" Margin="29,78,407,42" />
            <Image x:Name="cloud2" Source="Cloud.png" Height="115" Width="184" Margin="218,78,218,42" 
                Opacity="{Binding Opacity, ElementName=cloud1}"/>
            <Image x:Name="cloud3" Source="Cloud.png" Height="115" Width="184" Margin="402,78,34,42"
                Opacity="{Binding Opacity, ElementName=cloud1}"/>
        </StackPanel>

        <sdk:Label Height="28" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Canvas.Left="255" Canvas.Top="52" Width="120" Content="Capitals" Background="#FF68A0D8" Foreground="#FF6AC3FF" FontFamily="Comic Sans MS" FontStyle="Italic" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="20" Margin="250,-33,250,123"/>
        <sdk:Label x:Name="detailLabel" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="28" Canvas.Left="405" Canvas.Top="52" Canvas.ZIndex="1" FontFamily="Comic Sans MS" FontSize="14" Foreground="#FF5D5D5D" Content="PlayerName| PlayerScore" Margin="150,10,150,80" Width="320"/>
        <sdk:Label x:Name="option1"  HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="28" Margin="70,0,430,89" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="120" Foreground="#FF5D5D5D" FontFamily="Comic Sans MS" FontSize="13" Content="Maybe..."/>
        <sdk:Label x:Name="option2"  HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="28" Margin="250,0,250,89" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="120" Foreground="#FF5D5D5D" FontFamily="Comic Sans MS" FontSize="13" Content="Wrong?"/>
        <sdk:Label x:Name="option3"  HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="28" Margin="440,0,60,89" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="120" Foreground="#FF5D5D5D" FontFamily="Comic Sans MS" FontSize="13" Content="Correct?"/>

    </Grid>
    <sdk:Label x:Name="questionLabel" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="28" Canvas.Left="80" Canvas.Top="320" Width="480" Foreground="#FF5D5D5D" FontFamily="Comic Sans MS" FontSize="20" Content="Capital of which country?"/>
</Canvas>
```

Comment: I tried removing targetname from xaml and add the targets in my class by;

`(this.Resources["FadeImageStoryboard"] as Storyboard).Begin(cloud1,true);` etc... But it's not working this way.

Comment: Do you not mark your questions answered? This one's old and I had forgotten about it until another upvote came for it.

Comment: There isn't an answer to be marked as correct @ChrisW. Accepted it as you wished.

Comment: Ah if it's not an answer then don't mark it. Maybe I should have just asked if it worked for you. I just happened to notice only one or two of the questions you've asked here had ever been marked. No worries man, have a great weekend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately there's no way of setting multiple Target's within the same `DoubleAnimation` (though it would be nice if you could at least specify a `TargetType` to hit all your images right?? However nay, can't do that either...)

However... I have used a trick you can do to apply in your instance wherein you apply it to one, and allow it to feed the rest the same effect via Binding like;

```
<Storyboard x:Name="FadeImageStoryboard">
    <DoubleAnimation From="1.0" To="0.0" 
                     Duration="0:0:1"
                     RepeatBehavior="Forever" AutoReverse="True"
                     Storyboard.TargetName="cloud1" 
                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" />
</Storyboard>
```

Now we feed it to one Target, and let the others feed off of it...

```
<!-- Yea, I stripped your properties for the sake of example :P -->
<StackPanel>

    <Image x:Name="cloud1" Source="Cloud.png" Height="115" Width="184"/>

    <Image x:Name="cloud2" Source="Cloud.png" Height="115" Width="184" 
           Opacity="{Binding Opacity, ElementName=cloud1}"/>
    <Image x:Name="cloud3" Source="Cloud.png" Height="115" Width="184"
           Opacity="{Binding Opacity, ElementName=cloud1}"/>
    <Image x:Name="cloud4" Source="Cloud.png" Height="115" Width="184"
           Opacity="{Binding Opacity, ElementName=cloud1}"/>
    <Image x:Name="cloud5" Source="Cloud.png" Height="115" Width="184"
           Opacity="{Binding Opacity, ElementName=cloud1}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Not saying it's the "best" way, but it's the only way I've found over the years. Otherwise you're left with having to bite the bullet and just have a separate `DoubleAnimation` for each individual Target.

Hope this helps.

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Seems good and fair... However, I can only get one of my images to display. Any reason for this?

Comment: Only one image as in one image on all of them? In that case change your Image sources to have their respective image names/paths. Or if it's only one image period I'd assume it would be because of something else you have going on. All this way does is look at the Opacity property of Cloud1 and reflect it on the others.

Comment: It's only one image. Just to make it clear; 3x `<Image>` with the same source. I'll edit my question with the full XAML code. The class is pretty much what I've already written at the moment.

Comment: I suppose you could set the default Opacity on Image1 to =1 except I can't promise that would be the culprit considering that's the default value anyway.